# Convertir campo en obligatorio Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Les comento mi problema.

Tengo un sitio construido en WordPress el cual tiene tienda basada en Woocommerce.

La cuestión es que necesito que en su compra me hagan llegar un dato (correo electrónico).

Esto lo logre agregando el siguiente código al archivo *functions.php*

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'agrega_mi_campo_personalizado' );
 
function agrega_mi_campo_personalizado( $checkout ) {
 

    woocommerce_form_field( 'email_drive', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
        'label'         => __('E-Mail para agregar a las unidades VIP'),
        'placeholder'   => __('Ej: juan@gmail.com'),
        ), $checkout->get_value( 'email_drive' ));
 

}
```

El problema es que si aparece y todo bien pero aparece como "Opcional" y necesito que sea obligatorio, que podría hacer?

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

He conseguido resolverlo agregando "`'required' => 'true',`"

El codigo completo termino así:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_notes', 'agrega_mi_campo_personalizado' );
 
function agrega_mi_campo_personalizado( $checkout ) {
 

    woocommerce_form_field( 'email_drive', array(
        'type'          => 'text',
        'class'         => array('my-field-class form-row-wide'),
        'label'         => __('E-Mail para agregar a las unidades VIP'),
        'placeholder'   => __('Ej: juan@gmail.com'),
        'required'      => 'true',
        ), $checkout->get_value( 'email_drive' ));
 

}
```

Comment: En efecto esa es la respuesta técnica, pero algo me llama la atención, aun cuando permites la compra como invitado Wordpress exige el correo del cliente, ese no te servía??

Comment: @OCHOA Muchas veces el cliente pone un correo por ejemplo en Hotmail, Yahoo o cualquier otro proveedor y debe estar en Gmail, y de hecho desde que lo pusimos en efecto ponen uno de compra y otro para activar su servicio.